# Putting ELB in from of my ECS Cluster / Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, load-balancing, cloud-computing

I’m trying to put an ELB in from of my ECS service, using this [terraform file](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/aws.tf)

But applying it, gives the below error. Any ideas on the setup that I’ve gotten wrong?

```
$ terraform apply ...
aws_ecs_task_definition.beatthemarket-task: Refreshing state... (ID: beatthemarket)
aws_ecs_cluster.default: Refreshing state... (ID: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:186598327969:cluster/beatthemarket)
aws_iam_role.beathemarket-role: Refreshing state... (ID: beathemarket-role)
aws_elb.beathemarket-elb: Refreshing state... (ID: beathemarket-elb)
aws_ecs_service.beatthemarket_service: Creating...
  cluster:                                 "" => "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:186598327969:cluster/beatthemarket"
  deployment_maximum_percent:              "" => "200"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent:      "" => "100"
  desired_count:                           "" => "1"
  iam_role:                                "" => "arn:aws:iam::186598327969:role/beathemarket-role"
  load_balancer.#:                         "" => "1"
  load_balancer.2282006059.container_name: "" => "beatthemarket_service"
  load_balancer.2282006059.container_port: "" => "8080"
  load_balancer.2282006059.elb_name:       "" => "beathemarket-elb"
  name:                                    "" => "beatthemarket-service"
  task_definition:                         "" => "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:186598327969:task-definition/beatthemarket:2"
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_ecs_service.beatthemarket_service: InvalidParameterException: The container beatthemarket_service does not exist in the task definition.
    status code: 400, request id: 67ef4ee6-08e8-11e6-9b7a-95aa41386391
```

Answer (score 0):

Panagiotis Moustafellos in the **#devopsengineers** slack channel actually helped me fix this issue. Turns out that the `beatthemarket_service` container does not exist. (Confusingly) It's the `beatthemarket`task [definition name](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/task-definitions/beatthemarket.json#L3).

So I just replaced

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "beatthemarket_service" {
  name            = "beatthemarket-service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.default.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.beatthemarket-task.arn}"
  desired_count   = 1
  iam_role = "${aws_iam_role.beatthemarket_role.arn}"
  load_balancer {
    elb_name = "${aws_elb.beathemarket-elb.name}"
    container_name = "beatthemarket_service"
    container_port = 8080
  }
}
```

with

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "beatthemarket_service" {
  name            = "beatthemarket-service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.default.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.beatthemarket-task.arn}"
  desired_count   = 1
  iam_role = "${aws_iam_role.beatthemarket_role.arn}"
  load_balancer {
    elb_name = "${aws_elb.beathemarket-elb.name}"
    container_name = "beatthemarket"
    container_port = 8080
  }
}
```